# Set variable MySQL

Tags: mysql, parameters

I was trying to debug my MySQL stored procedure. While debugging, it turned out that, I cannot set my parameter, very interestingly. It's the following:

```
USE MyDatabase;

SET @myParam := 3;

Select @myParam;
```

What is missing?

Comment: can you show the whole code in your stored procedure?

Comment: What error are you getting?
By the way Where is the declaration???

Comment: This is the only code I'm executing. And there is no error. I only get a null row as the result.

Comment: :D. I was trying to write my stored procedure first, however after I see it didn't work; I saw that even this piece of code is not working. So, even only this piece code is not working in my shared godaddy hosting account's MySQL server.

Comment: What is the version of the MySQL server? `SELECT @@version;`

Comment: `SELECT @@version;` results `'5.0.96-log'`.